# Why is my image delaying when printed? Java

Tags: java

In my program, I am using a basic graphic component, displaying "Bugs in the code", printing lady bugs across the screen. Every time I run, or put a delay between the drawing of the bugs and the image, the bugs print first regardless. Here is my code:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ladyBugs
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Windows();
    }
}
class Windows extends Frame implements ActionListener, KeyListener, MouseListener
{
    final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    private double width = screenSize.getWidth();
    private double height = screenSize.getHeight();
    private int SCWIDTH = (int)width, SCHEIGHT = (int)760;
    private int whichScreen;
    private int turn;
    private Image myPic;
    private Image myScreen;
    private Graphics pen;

    public Windows()
    {
        out.println(SCWIDTH +" "+ SCHEIGHT);
        setSize(SCWIDTH, SCHEIGHT);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
            {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        myPic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\s613228\\Pictures\\moby.png");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        gameLoop();
    }
public void gameLoop()
{

}
public void paint(Graphics pen)
{
    if(whichScreen ==0)
    {
        setBounds(0, 0, SCWIDTH, SCHEIGHT);
        pen.setFont(new Font("verdana", Font.PLAIN, 50));
        pen.drawString("Cody's Test Program", SCWIDTH/5+50, SCHEIGHT/6); // Centered
        pen.drawImage(myPic, SCWIDTH/8, 150, 351, 144, this);
        pause(1000);
        whichScreen++;
    }
    else
        doubleBuffer(pen);
}
public void doubleBuffer(Graphics pen)
{
    Image code = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("c:\\users\\s613228\\pictures\\screenCapJCreator.png");
    pen.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pen.setFont(new Font("verdana", Font.PLAIN, 50));
    pen.drawString("Cody's Test Program", SCWIDTH/5+50, SCHEIGHT/6); // Centered
    pen.drawImage(code, 0, 0, SCWIDTH, SCHEIGHT, this);
    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    pen.setFont(new Font("verdana", Font.PLAIN, 60));
    pen.drawLine(0, 760, SCWIDTH, 760);
    pen.drawString("There are bugs in the code!", SCWIDTH/5, SCHEIGHT/6); // Centered
    for(int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
    {
        int random1 = (int)(random()*SCWIDTH*2-1)+1;
        int random2 = (int)(random()*1100-1)+200;
        int size = (int)(random()*100)+20;
        ladyBugs(random1, random2, size, pen);
        pause(15);
    }
}
public void ladyBugs(int x, int y, int size, Graphics pen)
{
    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Head
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/4, y/2-(size/2+size/4), size/2, size/2); 

    pen.setColor(Color.WHITE); // Whites of eyes
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/6, y/2-(size/2+size/6), size/8, size/8);
    pen.fillOval(x/2+(size/6-size/8), y/2-(size/2+size/6), size/8, size/8);
                               // Body
    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);   
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/2-4, y/2-size/2-4, size+8, size+8);
    pen.setColor(Color.RED);   
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/2, y/2-size/2, size, size);

    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Middle-Line Wing Separation
    pen.drawLine(x/2, y/2-size/2, x/2, y/2+size/2);
    pen.drawLine(x/2-1, y/2-size/2, x/2-1, y/2+size/2-1);
    pen.drawLine(x/2+1, y/2-size/2, x/2+1, y/2+size/2-1);

                               // Upper-Half Black Dots
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/4, y/2-size/4, size/5, size/5);
    pen.fillOval(x/2+(size/4-size/5), y/2-size/4, size/5, size/5);
                               // Lower-Half Black Dots
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/3, y/2+size/6, size/5, size/5);
    pen.fillOval(x/2+(size/3-size/5), y/2+size/6, size/5, size/5);
                               // Pupils
    pen.fillOval(x/2-(size/6-size/32), y/2-(size/2+size/7), size/12, size/16);
    pen.fillOval(x/2+(size/12-size/48), y/2-(size/2+size/7), size/12, size/16);
                               // Antenae
    int s = size/2;
    pen.drawArc(x/2-(s+(s/16)), y/2-size+(s/4), size/2, size/2, 90, -90);
    pen.drawArc(x/2+s/16, y/2-size+(s/4), size/2, size/2, 90, 90);
    pen.fillOval(x/2-(s+s/8)/2, y/2-(size-s/4)-s/15, s/10, s/10);
    pen.fillOval(x/2+s/2, y/2-(size-s/4)-s/15, s/10, s/10);
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{

}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{

}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{

}
public void keyEntered(KeyEvent e)
{

}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m)
{

}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m)
{

}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m)
{

}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m)
{

}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m)
{

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b)
{

}
public void update(Graphics G)
{
    paint(G);
}
public static void pause(long r)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(r);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        out.println(" Sleep Error "+e);
    }
}
}
```

What I'm looking for specifically is how to print the background image (a screencap of this code) prior to the bugs. This is the specific section:

```
public void paint(Graphics pen)
{
    if(whichScreen ==0)
    {
        setBounds(0, 0, SCWIDTH, SCHEIGHT);
        pen.setFont(new Font("verdana", Font.PLAIN, 50));
        pen.drawString("Cody's Test Program", SCWIDTH/5+50, SCHEIGHT/6); // Centered
        pen.drawImage(myPic, SCWIDTH/8, 150, 351, 144, this);
        pause(1000);
        whichScreen++;
    }
    else
        doubleBuffer(pen);
}
public void doubleBuffer(Graphics pen)
{
    Image code = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("c:\\users\\s613228\\pictures\\screenCapJCreator.png");
    pen.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pen.setFont(new Font("verdana", Font.PLAIN, 50));
    pen.drawString("Cody's Test Program", SCWIDTH/5+50, SCHEIGHT/6); // Centered
    pen.drawImage(code, 0, 0, SCWIDTH, SCHEIGHT, this);
    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    pen.setFont(new Font("verdana", Font.PLAIN, 60));
    pen.drawLine(0, 760, SCWIDTH, 760);
    pen.drawString("There are bugs in the code!", SCWIDTH/5, SCHEIGHT/6); // Centered
    for(int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
    {
        int random1 = (int)(random()*SCWIDTH*2-1)+1;
        int random2 = (int)(random()*1100-1)+200;
        int size = (int)(random()*100)+20;
        ladyBugs(random1, random2, size, pen);
        pause(15);
    }
}
public void ladyBugs(int x, int y, int size, Graphics pen)
{
    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Head
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/4, y/2-(size/2+size/4), size/2, size/2); 

    pen.setColor(Color.WHITE); // Whites of eyes
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/6, y/2-(size/2+size/6), size/8, size/8);
    pen.fillOval(x/2+(size/6-size/8), y/2-(size/2+size/6), size/8, size/8);
                               // Body
    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);   
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/2-4, y/2-size/2-4, size+8, size+8);
    pen.setColor(Color.RED);   
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/2, y/2-size/2, size, size);

    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Middle-Line Wing Separation
    pen.drawLine(x/2, y/2-size/2, x/2, y/2+size/2);
    pen.drawLine(x/2-1, y/2-size/2, x/2-1, y/2+size/2-1);
    pen.drawLine(x/2+1, y/2-size/2, x/2+1, y/2+size/2-1);

                               // Upper-Half Black Dots
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/4, y/2-size/4, size/5, size/5);
    pen.fillOval(x/2+(size/4-size/5), y/2-size/4, size/5, size/5);
                               // Lower-Half Black Dots
    pen.fillOval(x/2-size/3, y/2+size/6, size/5, size/5);
    pen.fillOval(x/2+(size/3-size/5), y/2+size/6, size/5, size/5);
                               // Pupils
    pen.fillOval(x/2-(size/6-size/32), y/2-(size/2+size/7), size/12, size/16);
    pen.fillOval(x/2+(size/12-size/48), y/2-(size/2+size/7), size/12, size/16);
                               // Antenae
    int s = size/2;
    pen.drawArc(x/2-(s+(s/16)), y/2-size+(s/4), size/2, size/2, 90, -90);
    pen.drawArc(x/2+s/16, y/2-size+(s/4), size/2, size/2, 90, 90);
    pen.fillOval(x/2-(s+s/8)/2, y/2-(size-s/4)-s/15, s/10, s/10);
    pen.fillOval(x/2+s/2, y/2-(size-s/4)-s/15, s/10, s/10);
}
```

Note: Of course the said image is directed from my C:\ drive so it obviously won't appear for y'all if recreated unless you use a similar picture.
Thank you

Comment: You should never call Thread.sleep() from your painting code, or anywhere else on the EDT.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Why exactly would it be an issue calling from it? All I use it for, or know what it does, is to pause (obviously) for a period of time, such as giving time for the user to read/process what's on screen

Comment: The EDT handles everything related to your GUI, from drawing to responding to user input. It needs to be as responsive as possible, and calling Thread.sleep() from the EDT will cause all kinds of strange behavior in your GUI. Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: In that case, then, how would I go about delaying the start-up "page"? I want it to where I can display the "Cody's Test Program" and allow time to read, then followed by the rest (ladybugs). I have done so previously but with a clicker of sorts. Just some simple spam-the-button "game" to test methods. Is the graphical component the only thing significantly altered by external referencing?

Comment: I'm not sure what your last question means, but for the rest of it, you should probably be using a Swing Timer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thank you a lot! And you're very helpful. Is this the source of my initial issue though? The reason of the delay?

Comment: It's certainly one of your problems. You're also loading the image every time paint() is called, which is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thank you for the source you supplied in a previous comment. I have read the java method for the timer, and it says I should form a task after implementing 
      new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();

Should I place this within the paint method, or externally, within its own method? Again, thank you. (Sorry, I'm not the best at this, and have difficulty visualizing)

Comment: Huh? You need to implement an ActionListener and pass that into the Timer constructor. The ActionListener can either be an anonymous class or a separate class that implements ActionListener. More info here: http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/swing/SwingTimers.jsp